# Use variables with dot in unix shell script

Tags: bash, unix

How do I use variables with dot in a Unix (Bash) shell script? I have the script below:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
"FILE=system.properties"
FILE=$1
echo $1
if [ -f "$FILE" ];
then
   echo "File $FILE exists"
else
   echo "File $FILE does not exist"
fi
```

This is basically what I need ⟶ `x=propertyfile`, and `propertyfile=$1.` Can someone please help me?

Comment: Is `FILE=system.properties` (without `""`) not working?

Comment: @Karthick - Posts need to be edited only to make them technically legible. You can not edit a grammatically correct post, and make it completely incorrect. Sorry but you have completely messed up my post. This just does not sound right grammatically.

Comment: if the words are not grammatically correct then how the members can understand or how you can expect the answer ???

Comment: Exactly my point. Your edit was very messed up. I restored it back to what I originally had!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't declare variable names with dots but you can use associative arrays to map keys, which is the more appropriate solution. This requires Bash 4.0.

```
declare -A FILE                      ## Declare variable as an associative array.
FILE[system.properties]="somefile"   ## Assign a value.
echo "${FILE[system.properties]}"    ## Access the value.
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that the line:

```
"FILE=system.properties"
```

tries to execute a command `FILE=system.properties` which most likely doesn't exist.  To assign to a variable, the quote must come after the equals:

```
FILE="system.properties"
```

It is a bit hard to tell from the question what you are after, but it sounds as if you might be after indirect variable names.  Unfortunately, standard editions of `bash` don't allow dots in variable names.

However, if you used an underscore instead, then:

```
FILE="system_properties"
system_properties="$1"
echo "${FILE}"
echo "${!FILE}"
```

will echo:

```
system_properties
what-was-passed-as-the-first-argument
```