# How to create and assign a variable name with special character in bash

Tags: bash, shell

Sorry if this question is repeated.

how can I create a variable a.b and assign a value to it.

```
----------
root@IN2268980W3:# a=1
root@IN2268980W3:# a.b=1
a.b=1: command not found
root@IN2268980W3:# a.b='1'
a.b=1: command not found
root@IN2268980W3:# 'a.b'='1'
a.b=1: command not found
root@IN2268980W3:# 'a\.b'='1'
a\.b=1: command not found
root@IN2268980W3:#
-----
```

I need this for testing.

Comment: You most likely can't. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25356806/11688567

Comment: *I need this for testing.* Unless you're testing if that'll give an error, no you don't.

Comment: If that is the case, how azure devops is creating variables like $(Build.SourceBranchName), echo $(Build.SourceRepository.Name) etc. When echo they print the right values.
I need to run tests and perform dev activities by assigning these values in my devops agent machine.

Comment: That's not bash syntax (or rather, it is, but it'd run `Build.SourceRepository.Name` as a command rather than treat it as a variable). I'm not sure where you're running that command, but it's not bash, so that's not a bash variable.

Answer (score 0):

Standard editions of bash don't allow dots (.) in variable names. The backslash escape \ does not fix the problem as well.